# How to auto grow just the width in textarea?

Tags: css, reactjs

I was wondering if there is a way to just autogrow the width of a textarea. I understand that there is multiple ways to grow the height but i havent found something to grow just the width.
To give a visual, im looking to get something sort of like how imessage extends the width of the blue circle to fit the text inside.
If theres anyway to do this in react and css thats fantastic
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

What I do in my webpages is place the textarea tag in a div tag, setting the width of the textarea to 100% and then allowing the div to be responsive based on how big the screen size is

```
...
#textfield {
width: //insert your desired width, like 80% or 300px//;
}

textarea {
width: 100%;
}
...
<div id="textfield">
   <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```